# TypeError: DataModule.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset'

Tags: python

**Describe the bug**
Got this error: TypeError: DataModule.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset', even though the docs stated that it's part of the parameters.

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:
I just ran this:

```
from climate_learn.utils.datetime import Year, Days, Hours
from climate_learn.data import DataModule

data_module = DataModule(
    dataset = "ERA5",
    task = "forecasting",
    root_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Climate/.climate_tutorial/data/weatherbench/era5/5.625/",
    in_vars = ["2m_temperature"],
    out_vars = ["2m_temperature"],
    train_start_year = Year(1979),
    val_start_year = Year(2015),
    test_start_year = Year(2017),
    end_year = Year(2018),
    pred_range = Days(3),
    subsample = Hours(6),
    batch_size = 128,
    num_workers = 1
)
```

Error traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
[<ipython-input-11-6ff523560500>](https://localhost:8080/#) in <cell line: 4>()
      2 from climate_learn.data import DataModule
      3 
----> 4 data_module = DataModule(
      5     dataset = "ERA5",
      6     task = "forecasting",

TypeError: DataModule.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dataset'
```

**Expected behavior**
Code can run smoothly

**Screenshots**
[image]

[image]

**Environment**

- OS: M1 Macbook Air
- Python version: Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr  5 2023, 14:15:10) [GCC 9.4.0]
- Environment:

```
Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------------------
absl-py                       1.4.0
aiohttp                       3.8.4
aiosignal                     1.3.1
alabaster                     0.7.13
albumentations                1.2.1
altair                        4.2.2
anyio                         3.6.2
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arviz                         0.15.1
astropy                       5.2.2
astunparse                    1.6.3
async-timeout                 4.0.2
attrs                         23.1.0
audioread                     3.0.0
autograd                      1.5
Babel                         2.12.1
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.2
bleach                        6.0.0
blis                          0.7.9
blosc2                        2.0.0
bokeh                         2.4.3
branca                        0.6.0
CacheControl                  0.12.11
cached-property               1.5.2
cachetools                    5.3.0
catalogue                     2.0.8
cdsapi                        0.6.1
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
cftime                        1.6.2
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.12
chex                          0.1.7
click                         8.1.3
climate-learn                 0.0.2
cloudpickle                   2.2.1
cmake                         3.25.2
cmdstanpy                     1.1.0
colorcet                      3.0.1
colorlover                    0.3.0
community                     1.0.0b1
confection                    0.0.4
cons                          0.4.5
contextlib2                   0.6.0.post1
contourpy                     1.0.7
convertdate                   2.4.0
cryptography                  40.0.2
cufflinks                     0.17.3
cupy-cuda11x                  11.0.0
cvxopt                        1.3.0
cvxpy                         1.3.1
cycler                        0.11.0
cymem                         2.0.7
Cython                        0.29.34
dask                          2022.12.1
datascience                   0.17.6
db-dtypes                     1.1.1
dbus-python                   1.2.16
debugpy                       1.6.6
decorator                     4.4.2
defusedxml                    0.7.1
distributed                   2022.12.1
dlib                          19.24.1
dm-tree                       0.1.8
docker-pycreds                0.4.0
docutils                      0.16
dopamine-rl                   4.0.6
duckdb                        0.7.1
earthengine-api               0.1.350
easydict                      1.10
ecos                          2.0.12
editdistance                  0.6.2
en-core-web-sm                3.5.0
entrypoints                   0.4
ephem                         4.1.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
etils                         1.2.0
etuples                       0.3.8
exceptiongroup                1.1.1
fastai                        2.7.12
fastcore                      1.5.29
fastdownload                  0.0.7
fastjsonschema                2.16.3
fastprogress                  1.0.3
fastrlock                     0.8.1
filelock                      3.12.0
firebase-admin                5.3.0
Flask                         2.2.4
flatbuffers                   23.3.3
flax                          0.6.9
folium                        0.14.0
fonttools                     4.39.3
frozendict                    2.3.7
frozenlist                    1.3.3
fsspec                        2023.4.0
future                        0.18.3
gast                          0.4.0
GDAL                          3.3.2
gdown                         4.6.6
gensim                        4.3.1
geographiclib                 2.0
geopy                         2.3.0
gin-config                    0.5.0
gitdb                         4.0.10
GitPython                     3.1.31
glob2                         0.7
google                        2.0.3
google-api-core               2.11.0
google-api-python-client      2.84.0
google-auth                   2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2          0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib          1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery         3.9.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.19.1
google-cloud-core             2.3.2
google-cloud-datastore        2.15.1
google-cloud-firestore        2.11.0
google-cloud-language         2.9.1
google-cloud-storage          2.8.0
google-cloud-translate        3.11.1
google-colab                  1.0.0
google-crc32c                 1.5.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
google-resumable-media        2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos      1.59.0
googledrivedownloader         0.4
graphviz                      0.20.1
greenlet                      2.0.2
grpcio                        1.54.0
grpcio-status                 1.48.2
gspread                       3.4.2
gspread-dataframe             3.0.8
gym                           0.25.2
gym-notices                   0.0.8
h5netcdf                      1.1.0
h5py                          3.8.0
hijri-converter               2.3.1
holidays                      0.23
holoviews                     1.15.4
html5lib                      1.1
httpimport                    1.3.0
httplib2                      0.21.0
huggingface-hub               0.14.1
humanize                      4.6.0
hyperopt                      0.2.7
idna                          3.4
imageio                       2.25.1
imageio-ffmpeg                0.4.8
imagesize                     1.4.1
imbalanced-learn              0.10.1
imgaug                        0.4.0
importlib-metadata            4.13.0
importlib-resources           5.12.0
imutils                       0.5.4
inflect                       6.0.4
iniconfig                     2.0.0
intel-openmp                  2023.1.0
ipykernel                     5.5.6
ipython                       7.34.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipython-sql                   0.4.1
ipywidgets                    7.7.1
itsdangerous                  2.1.2
jax                           0.4.8
jaxlib                        0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn86
jieba                         0.42.1
Jinja2                        3.1.2
joblib                        1.2.0
jsonpickle                    3.0.1
jsonschema                    4.3.3
jupyter-client                6.1.12
jupyter-console               6.1.0
jupyter_core                  5.3.0
jupyter-server                1.24.0
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets            3.0.7
kaggle                        1.5.13
keras                         2.12.0
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
korean-lunar-calendar         0.3.1
langcodes                     3.3.0
lazy_loader                   0.2
libclang                      16.0.0
librosa                       0.10.0.post2
lightgbm                      3.3.5
lightning-utilities           0.8.0
lit                           16.0.2
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
logical-unification           0.4.5
LunarCalendar                 0.0.9
lxml                          4.9.2
Markdown                      3.4.3
markdown-it-py                2.2.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.2
matplotlib                    3.7.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
matplotlib-venn               0.11.9
mdurl                         0.1.2
miniKanren                    1.0.3
missingno                     0.5.2
mistune                       0.8.4
mizani                        0.8.1
mkl                           2019.0
ml-dtypes                     0.1.0
mlxtend                       0.14.0
more-itertools                9.1.0
moviepy                       1.0.3
mpmath                        1.3.0
msgpack                       1.0.5
multidict                     6.0.4
multipledispatch              0.6.0
multitasking                  0.0.11
murmurhash                    1.0.9
music21                       8.1.0
natsort                       8.3.1
nbclient                      0.7.4
nbconvert                     6.5.4
nbformat                      5.8.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
netCDF4                       1.6.3
networkx                      3.1
nibabel                       3.0.2
nltk                          3.8.1
notebook                      6.4.8
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.4
numpy                         1.22.4
oauth2client                  4.1.3
oauthlib                      3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python         4.7.0.72
opencv-python                 4.7.0.72
opencv-python-headless        4.7.0.72
openpyxl                      3.0.10
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
optax                         0.1.5
orbax-checkpoint              0.2.1
osqp                          0.6.2.post8
packaging                     23.1
palettable                    3.3.3
pandas                        1.5.3
pandas-datareader             0.10.0
pandas-gbq                    0.17.9
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.14.4
param                         1.13.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.4.0
pathlib                       1.0.1
pathtools                     0.1.2
pathy                         0.10.1
patsy                         0.5.3
pep517                        0.13.0
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        8.4.0
pip                           23.0.1
pip-tools                     6.6.2
platformdirs                  3.3.0
plotly                        5.13.1
plotnine                      0.10.1
pluggy                        1.0.0
polars                        0.17.3
pooch                         1.6.0
portpicker                    1.3.9
prefetch-generator            1.0.3
preshed                       3.0.8
prettytable                   0.7.2
proglog                       0.1.10
progressbar2                  4.2.0
prometheus-client             0.16.0
promise                       2.3
prompt-toolkit                3.0.38
prophet                       1.1.2
proto-plus                    1.22.2
protobuf                      3.20.3
psutil                        5.9.5
psycopg2                      2.9.6
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
py-cpuinfo                    9.0.0
py4j                          0.10.9.7
pyarrow                       9.0.0
pyasn1                        0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                0.3.0
pycocotools                   2.0.6
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.5.0
pydantic                      1.10.7
pydata-google-auth            1.7.0
pydot                         1.4.2
pydot-ng                      2.0.0
pydotplus                     2.0.2
PyDrive                       1.3.1
pyerfa                        2.0.0.3
pygame                        2.3.0
Pygments                      2.14.0
PyGObject                     3.36.0
pymc                          5.1.2
PyMeeus                       0.5.12
pymystem3                     0.2.0
PyOpenGL                      3.1.6
pyparsing                     3.0.9
pyrsistent                    0.19.3
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytensor                      2.10.1
pytest                        7.2.2
python-apt                    0.0.0
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-louvain                0.16
python-slugify                8.0.1
python-utils                  3.5.2
pytorch-lightning             2.0.2
pytz                          2022.7.1
pytz-deprecation-shim         0.1.0.post0
pyviz-comms                   2.2.1
PyWavelets                    1.4.1
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         23.2.1
qdldl                         0.1.7
qudida                        0.0.4
regex                         2022.10.31
requests                      2.27.1
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
requests-unixsocket           0.2.0
rich                          13.3.4
rpy2                          3.5.5
rsa                           4.9
scikit-image                  0.19.3
scikit-learn                  1.2.2
scipy                         1.10.1
scs                           3.2.3
seaborn                       0.12.2
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
sentry-sdk                    1.22.1
setproctitle                  1.3.2
setuptools                    67.7.2
shapely                       2.0.1
six                           1.16.0
sklearn-pandas                2.2.0
smart-open                    6.3.0
smmap                         5.0.0
sniffio                       1.3.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soundfile                     0.12.1
soupsieve                     2.4.1
soxr                          0.3.5
spacy                         3.5.2
spacy-legacy                  3.0.12
spacy-loggers                 1.0.4
Sphinx                        3.5.4
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
SQLAlchemy                    2.0.10
sqlparse                      0.4.4
srsly                         2.4.6
statsmodels                   0.13.5
sympy                         1.11.1
tables                        3.8.0
tabulate                      0.8.10
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.2.2
tensorboard                   2.12.2
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.12.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.8.3
tensorflow-estimator          2.12.0
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.12.0
tensorflow-hub                0.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.13.1
tensorflow-probability        0.19.0
tensorstore                   0.1.36
termcolor                     2.3.0
terminado                     0.17.1
text-unidecode                1.3
textblob                      0.17.1
tf-slim                       1.1.0
thinc                         8.1.9
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
tifffile                      2023.4.12
timm                          0.6.13
tinycss2                      1.2.1
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
toolz                         0.12.0
torch                         2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio                    2.0.1+cu118
torchdata                     0.6.0
torchmetrics                  0.11.4
torchsummary                  1.5.1
torchtext                     0.15.1
torchvision                   0.15.1+cu118
tornado                       6.2
tqdm                          4.65.0
traitlets                     5.7.1
triton                        2.0.0
tweepy                        4.13.0
typer                         0.7.0
typing_extensions             4.5.0
tzdata                        2023.3
tzlocal                       4.3
uritemplate                   4.1.1
urllib3                       1.26.15
vega-datasets                 0.9.0
wandb                         0.15.2
wasabi                        1.1.1
wcwidth                       0.2.6
webcolors                     1.13
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              1.5.1
Werkzeug                      2.3.0
wheel                         0.40.0
widgetsnbextension            3.6.4
wordcloud                     1.8.2.2
wrapt                         1.14.1
xarray                        2022.12.0
xarray-einstats               0.5.1
xgboost                       1.7.5
xlrd                          2.0.1
yarl                          1.9.2
yellowbrick                   1.5
yfinance                      0.2.18
zict                          3.0.0
zipp                          3.15.0
```